# How best to save oracle data pulled via SQL

Tags: c#, json, winforms

So i am working on a personal project for work where i want to pull data from a series of Oracle tables and save them off. The data shown in the winforms will be the most recent pull, but the user will have the option to view earlier files.

I have most of this working using the newtonsoft JSON package, serializing to a file and deserializing into a datadridview.

What I am now trying to do is query from this information and have hit a wall, causing me to wonder if JSON was the correct path to take. Perhaps I should have done XML or saving the data directly to excel files?

I want to use this queried data to populate datagridviews, generate metrics, graphs, etc.

Making my question more specific to JSON, as that is where I am right now.
I need to query from a JSON file.
Here is my code below for identifying the most recent file in the folder and populating the datagridview with it

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp\GRMReportingJSONfiles\");
        var myFile = (from f in directory.GetFiles()
                      orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
                      select f).First();

        //DataTable assgnDT = new DataTable();

        using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"C:\temp\GRMReportingJSONfiles\" + myFile))
        {

            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            IEnumerable<AssgnData> movie2 = (IEnumerable<AssgnData>)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(IEnumerable<AssgnData>));
            //dataGridView1.DataSource = movie2;
            //AssgnData movie2 = (AssgnData)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(AssgnData));
            //assgnDT
        }



    }
    public class AssgnData
    {
        public string PROJ_BU { get; set; }
        public string EMPLID { get; set; }
        public string Resource_Name { get; set; }
        public string mnth1 { get; set; }
        public string mnth2 { get; set; }
    }
```

got the LINQ query to work. only shows 2 rows instead of 10

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"C:\temp\GRMReportingJSONfiles\" + myFile))
        {

            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            IEnumerable<AssgnData> movie2 = (IEnumerable<AssgnData>)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(IEnumerable<AssgnData>));

            dataGridView1.DataSource = (from p in movie2
                                  where p.PROJECT_ID == "111111"
                                  select p).ToArray();

            //dataGridView1.DataSource = peopleOverForty;
            //AssgnData movie2 = (AssgnData)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(AssgnData));
            //assgnDT
        }
```

Comment: What *specific* issue are you encountering? I think JSON is a great data format. You are probably getting stuck somewhere, but you need to post the relevant code if you want us to help.

Comment: Thank you, yes I was wondering if I needed to be more specific but Im really open to doing this in any method.
I suppose right now I need to query from JSON is where im stuck

Comment: You have `IEnumerable<AssgnData>` in `movie2`, so you could use any of the LINQ extensions such as `.Where()`. What is your query? How do you want to filter the data?

Comment: right now I just want to filter by field values. so there are 94,000 rows in my query and lets say i want to filter on a specific team. Typically I'd just do select * where Team='1000'. My filters will get more complicated than that later as I aggregate the data.
My goal was to only have the user pull the data once, as the pull can take 5 to 10 minutes. and then I can manipulate and filter all I want without impact to the user

Comment: Hi Dan, can you offer your comment as an answer, I'd like to mark it as such. you pushed me in the right direction further toward json and I was able to get the LINQ to work after some fiddling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the LINQ query to work. only shows 2 rows instead of 10

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"C:\temp\GRMReportingJSONfiles\" + myFile))
    {

        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        IEnumerable<AssgnData> movie2 = (IEnumerable<AssgnData>)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(IEnumerable<AssgnData>));

        dataGridView1.DataSource = (from p in movie2
                              where p.PROJECT_ID == "111111"
                              select p).ToArray();

        //dataGridView1.DataSource = peopleOverForty;
        //AssgnData movie2 = (AssgnData)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(AssgnData));
        //assgnDT
    }
```